# c# Best type/collection/list/dataset to handle super large data (csv/tab files)

Tags: c#, linq, collections, dataset, large-files

I am building one WPF (MVVM) app that handles really large csv files. We are talking about 1GB to 10GB.

I open the file and parse it with File.ReadLines into a List of following class:

```
public class FileLine
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; } 
    public string Message { get; set; } //Usually around 256 characters
    public string Info1 { get; set; } //Exact 56 characters
    public string Info2 { get; set; } //Exact 4 characters
    //and so on
}
```

... then I do all sort of data manipulation, queries, charts... you name it... everything using Linq.

We are testing a 1.8GB file and when it is opened, the process takes around 2GB of memory.

Eventually, when my customer needs to open his 10GB file it will be impossible, because it is going to take 12GB+ of Memory.
What is the best type/collection/list/dataset to this kind of work?

Comment: I am afraid someone will tell me to use SQL Server... just saying.

Comment: This will take forever.. use something more robust to store the data, for example store it into `Oracle DB, || Sql Server`

Comment: Do you really need to load it all into memory at once? What is your use case here? I'm afraid the question is too broad as it currently stands.

Comment: `Eventually, when my customer needs to open his 10GB file it will be impossible, because it is going to take 12GB+ of Memory.`  No, that's [just not true](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx).  (Although it's a very bad idea to try to load that much data into memory, even though it's possible.  Oh, and of course there are systems that just will actually have 12+GB of RAM, but that's also not really the point here.)

Comment: @MethodMan, I was afraid of that :) .

Comment: @DavidG This App will do automatic analysis of log files of one specific server product. I thought on get 1000 lines and dispose it, then get next 1000 thousand and dispose it. The problem with that is that for every other analysis, I need to read the file and work again in batches. Better to have everything in memory, or in a SQL Server. But if I want everything in memory which type/collection/list/dataset performs better?

Comment: If you want everything memory - array of structs. But I think you should consider some sort of a tiny `IEnumerable<T>` wrapper around memory mapped file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion the best thing is to read the file, process it, and dispose all the rest, sticking only with the result.

Another possibility was to use database, but it would add too much complexity, although it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

When i've had to do something like this before I handled it by having a container object that held a list of dictionaries.  At the time I thought the limit would/should be 2^32 number of elements, but an exception for exceeding the collection was thrown  well before getting 2^32 elements and still had many GB of ram left.   Say you want a Dictionary, something like this should work until you really do exhaust all physical and virtual memory...  A possible solution for you follows...  I remember when I worked on this a few years ago the server actually had 512Gb of ram, I'm sure they have ones with more now...  Anyway that's a separate story.

```
   public class MyHugeDictionary  
   {  
        List<Dictionary<typea, typeb> allDict= null;  
        Dictionary<typea, typeb> currDictionary ;  

        MyHugeDictiionary()  
        {  
            allDict = new List<Dictionary<typea, typeb>();  
            currDictionary = new Dictionary<typea, typeb);  
            allDict.Add(currDictionary);  
        }  

        public bool ItemExists( typea, typeb)  
        {  
            foreach( KeyValue<Dictionary<typea, typeb> kv in allDict)  
            {  
                if( kv.ContainsKey(typea) )  
                {  
                    return true;  
                }  
            }  
            return false;  
        }  

        public Add( typea a, typeb b)  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                if( !ItemExist( tyepa, typeb) )  // find if items is in any other dictionary first  
                {  
                    currDictionary.Add( a, b) ;  
                }  
                else  { // handle dups... ; }  
            }  
            catch( CollectionSizeError x)   // look-up for actual exception
            {  
                currDictionary = CreateDictiionary();  
                allDict.Add( currDictionary ) ;  
                currDictionary.Add( a,b);  
            }  
            catch( OutOfMemory y)     // look-up for actual exception
            {  
                // oops game over for real now :(  
            }  
         }  
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

See this:

https://github.com/aumcode/nfx/tree/master/Source/NFX/ApplicationModel/Pile
https://www.infoq.com/articles/Big-Memory-Part-3

You can store whatever you want - no pauses.
The problem with large collections is:
a. They are not really designed to hold very many entries (i.e. Dictionary never shrinks back to zero size)
b. You get GC stalls/pauses when you have too many objects

see the links above - what we did is "hiding" of data from GC as described in the article. This way you can store millions of objects using LocalCache class as a dictionary.

For large memory apps in net - remember to enable 64 bit and set GC to SERVER mode in your app config file